# Tor does not create new .onion address after reinstall to v3

Tags: tor-install

My tor server stopped working vecause v2 has been deprecated. I could not get it into creating new v3 .onion address, so I uninstalled tor and installed again. Here is part of my torrc file:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

I would expect that when I start tor service (by `service tor start`), it will generate new .onion address in file `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/host`, but it does not.

In the log, there is entry

```
Dec 12 23:26:42 acc-box2 systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Dec 12 23:26:42 acc-box2 systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

but nothing about connecting to circuits. What can be wrong please?

Comment: You need to delete the old onion service in `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/` before tor will create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

To enforce Tor to re-create the keys you need to make the target directory empty, that's how it works

Comment: Yes the target directory is empty. Still..

Comment: can you run tor in verbose mode? Looks like an answer will be in a verbose logs.

Comment: When I run tor as service it creates entry in syslog that tor is running on TCP service, but it looks like tor is not running as hidden service - it does not create any file in hidden_directory. When I try to run tor as command, I get error `tor: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.1.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I am aware that installing libevent is not easy. Morevover, my system says that most recent version of libevent-2.1 is installed and I also found somewhere that recent version of tor does not need libevent library.

Comment: that can be a key: populate LD_LIBRARY_PATH with all the required libraries' locations. the list is given with `ldd /full/path/to/executable` command

Comment: Sorry I get ```ldd: No such file or directory```, also I am not linux expert, so I do not know how to "populate LD_LIBRARY_PATH with all the required libraries' locations"

Comment: try the full path: `/sbin/ldd` or `/usr/sbin/ldd` - in some Linux distributions sbin's are not in a PATH by default, which is highly questionable practice just by itself

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve things in the strange way. It looks like when I uninstalled tor v2 the `libevent-2.1.so.6` got wiped out. Probably by my other actions. When I reinstalled tor and I was trying to reinstall libevent, other versions were installed, like `libevent-2.2.so.1`, but tor was still complaining about missing `libevent-2.1.so.6`. Fortunately I found it in old backup and I just copied it to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. The tor from the command line started to work, but it did not work as a service. I think I fixed that by changing owner of `hidden_service` directory to debian-tor. Then service started to work after I restarted computer. Hope this will help someone, it took me four evenings to fix.